# Where is Vue 3 versions list?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

On the [Vue installation page](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#cdn) they recommend including this to html "for prototyping purposes":

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

And also warn that it is recommended to link to a specific version "for production":

> For production, we recommend linking to a specific version number and build to avoid unexpected breakage from newer versions.

But where is the list of the available versions?

I searched on the [installation page](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#cdn). I went to their Github and didn't find a list there. Where do I look? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their GitHub page (Google query "vue 3 releases"):
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/releases

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vue's [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/releases) indicated in the other answer, there are other options to determine the available versions of Vue.

### Option 1: NPM version page

Use Vue's [NPM version page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue). The version numbers listed in the "Version" column can be copied exactly into the URL for `unpkg.com`, as they use the same versioning from NPM (e.g., `https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.26`). The same is true for the tags, such as `latest`, `next`, and `beta` (e.g., `https://unpkg.com/vue@beta` resolves to `https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.0-beta.8` as of this writing).

[image]

### Option 2: Unpkg's browse-package page

Use the version dropdown on `unpkg.com`'s browse-package page at `https://unpkg.com/vue/` (note the trailing slash) or `https://unpkg.com/browse/vue/`:

[image: screenshot of unpkg browse-package page]

### Option 3: Command line with `npm info`

Use `npm info vue versions` to quickly list all available Vue versions on the command line:

```sh
$ npm info vue versions
[
  '0.0.0',          '0.6.0',                '0.7.0',
  '0.7.1',          '0.7.3',                '0.7.4',
  '0.7.5',          '0.7.6',                '0.8.0',
  '0.8.1',          '0.8.2',                '0.8.3',
  '0.8.4',          '0.8.6',                '0.8.7',
  '0.8.8',          '0.9.0',                '0.9.1',
  '0.9.2',          '0.9.3',                '0.10.0',
  '0.10.1',         '0.10.2',               '0.10.3',
  '0.10.4',         '0.10.5',               '0.10.6',
  '0.11.0-rc',      '0.11.0-rc2',           '0.11.0-rc3',
  '0.11.0',         '0.11.1',               '0.11.2',
  '0.11.3',         '0.11.4',               '0.11.5',
  '0.11.6',         '0.11.7',               '0.11.8',
  '0.11.9',         '0.11.10',              '0.12.0-beta1',
  '0.12.0-beta2',   '0.12.0-beta3',         '0.12.0-beta4',
  '0.12.0-beta5',   '0.12.0-csp',           '0.12.0-rc',
  '0.12.0-rc2',     '0.12.0',               '0.12.1-csp',
  '0.12.1-csp.1',   '0.12.1-csp.2',         '0.12.1',
  '0.12.2',         '0.12.3',               '0.12.4',
  '0.12.5-csp',     '0.12.5',               '0.12.6-csp',
  '0.12.6',         '0.12.7-csp',           '0.12.7',
  '0.12.8-csp',     '0.12.8',               '0.12.9-csp',
  '0.12.9',         '0.12.10-csp',          '0.12.10',
  '0.12.11-csp',    '0.12.11',              '0.12.12-csp',
  '0.12.12',        '0.12.13-csp',          '0.12.13',
  '0.12.14-csp',    '0.12.14',              '0.12.15-csp',
  '0.12.15',        '0.12.16-csp',          '0.12.16',
  '1.0.0-alpha.1',  '1.0.0-alpha.2',        '1.0.0-alpha.3',
  '1.0.0-alpha.4',  '1.0.0-alpha.5',        '1.0.0-alpha.6',
  '1.0.0-alpha.7',  '1.0.0-alpha.8',        '1.0.0-beta.1',
  '1.0.0-beta.2',   '1.0.0-beta.3',         '1.0.0-beta.4',
  '1.0.0-csp',      '1.0.0-migration',      '1.0.0-rc.1',
  '1.0.0-rc.2',     '1.0.0-rc.2-migration', '1.0.0',
  '1.0.1',          '1.0.2',                '1.0.3',
  '1.0.4',          '1.0.5',                '1.0.6',
  '1.0.7',          '1.0.8',                '1.0.9',
  '1.0.10-csp',     '1.0.10',               '1.0.11-csp',
  '1.0.11',         '1.0.12-csp',           '1.0.12-csp-1',
  '1.0.12',         '1.0.13-csp',           '1.0.13',
  '1.0.14-csp',     '1.0.14',               '1.0.15-csp',
  '1.0.15',         '1.0.16-csp',           '1.0.16',
  '1.0.17-csp',     '1.0.17',               '1.0.18-csp',
  '1.0.18',         '1.0.19-csp',           '1.0.19',
  '1.0.20-csp',     '1.0.20',               '1.0.21-csp',
  '1.0.21',         '1.0.22-csp',           '1.0.22',
  '1.0.23-csp',     '1.0.23',               '1.0.24-csp',
  '1.0.24',         '1.0.25-csp',           '1.0.25',
  '1.0.26-csp',     '1.0.26',               '1.0.27-csp',
  '1.0.27',         '1.0.28-csp',           '1.0.28',
  '2.0.0-alpha.1',  '2.0.0-alpha.2',        '2.0.0-alpha.3',
  '2.0.0-alpha.4',  '2.0.0-alpha.5',        '2.0.0-alpha.6',
  '2.0.0-alpha.7',  '2.0.0-alpha.8',        '2.0.0-beta.1',
  '2.0.0-beta.2',   '2.0.0-beta.3',         '2.0.0-beta.4',
  '2.0.0-beta.5',   '2.0.0-beta.6',         '2.0.0-beta.7',
  '2.0.0-beta.8',   '2.0.0-rc.1',           '2.0.0-rc.2',
  '2.0.0-rc.3',     '2.0.0-rc.4',           '2.0.0-rc.5',
  '2.0.0-rc.6',     '2.0.0-rc.7',           '2.0.0-rc.8',
  '2.0.0',          '2.0.1',                '2.0.2',
  '2.0.3',          '2.0.4',                '2.0.5',
  '2.0.6',          '2.0.7',                '2.0.8',
  '2.1.0',          '2.1.1',                '2.1.2',
  '2.1.3',          '2.1.4',                '2.1.5',
  '2.1.6',          '2.1.7',                '2.1.8',
  '2.1.9',          '2.1.10',               '2.2.0-beta.1',
  '2.2.0-beta.2',   '2.2.0',                '2.2.1',
  '2.2.2',          '2.2.3',                '2.2.4',
  '2.2.5',          '2.2.6',                '2.3.0-beta.1',
  '2.3.0',          '2.3.1',                '2.3.2',
  '2.3.3',          '2.3.4',                '2.4.0',
  '2.4.1',          '2.4.2',                '2.4.3',
  '2.4.4',          '2.5.0',                '2.5.1',
  '2.5.2',          '2.5.3',                '2.5.4',
  '2.5.5',          '2.5.6',                '2.5.7',
  '2.5.8',          '2.5.9',                '2.5.10',
  '2.5.11',         '2.5.12',               '2.5.13',
  '2.5.14',         '2.5.15',               '2.5.16',
  '2.5.17-beta.0',  '2.5.17',               '2.5.18-beta.0',
  '2.5.18',         '2.5.19',               '2.5.20',
  '2.5.21',         '2.5.22',               '2.6.0-beta.1',
  '2.6.0-beta.2',   '2.6.0-beta.3',         '2.6.0',
  '2.6.1',          '2.6.2',                '2.6.3',
  '2.6.4',          '2.6.5',                '2.6.6',
  '2.6.7',          '2.6.8',                '2.6.9',
  '2.6.10',         '2.6.11',               '2.6.12',
  '2.6.13',         '2.6.14',               '3.0.0-alpha.0',
  '3.0.0-alpha.1',  '3.0.0-alpha.2',        '3.0.0-alpha.3',
  '3.0.0-alpha.4',  '3.0.0-alpha.5',        '3.0.0-alpha.6',
  '3.0.0-alpha.7',  '3.0.0-alpha.8',        '3.0.0-alpha.9',
  '3.0.0-alpha.10', '3.0.0-alpha.11',       '3.0.0-alpha.12',
  '3.0.0-alpha.13', '3.0.0-beta.1',         '3.0.0-beta.2',
  '3.0.0-beta.3',   '3.0.0-beta.4',         '3.0.0-beta.5',
  '3.0.0-beta.6',   '3.0.0-beta.7',         '3.0.0-beta.8',
  '3.0.0-beta.9',   '3.0.0-beta.10',        '3.0.0-beta.11',
  '3.0.0-beta.12',  '3.0.0-beta.13',        '3.0.0-beta.14',
  '3.0.0-beta.15',  '3.0.0-beta.16',        '3.0.0-beta.17',
  '3.0.0-beta.18',  '3.0.0-beta.19',        '3.0.0-beta.20',
  '3.0.0-beta.21',  '3.0.0-beta.22',        '3.0.0-beta.23',
  '3.0.0-beta.24',  '3.0.0-rc.1',           '3.0.0-rc.2',
  '3.0.0-rc.3',     '3.0.0-rc.4',           '3.0.0-rc.5',
  '3.0.0-rc.6',     '3.0.0-rc.7',           '3.0.0-rc.8',
  '3.0.0-rc.9',     '3.0.0-rc.10',          '3.0.0-rc.11',
  '3.0.0-rc.12',    '3.0.0-rc.13',          '3.0.0',
  '3.0.1',          '3.0.2',                '3.0.3',
  '3.0.4',          '3.0.5',                '3.0.6',
  '3.0.7',          '3.0.8',                '3.0.9',
  '3.0.10',         '3.0.11',               '3.1.0-beta.1',
  '3.1.0-beta.2',   '3.1.0-beta.3',         '3.1.0-beta.4',
  '3.1.0-beta.5',   '3.1.0-beta.6',         '3.1.0-beta.7',
  '3.1.0',          '3.1.1',                '3.1.2',
  '3.1.3',          '3.1.4',                '3.1.5',
  '3.2.0-beta.1',   '3.2.0-beta.2',         '3.2.0-beta.3',
  '3.2.0-beta.4',   '3.2.0-beta.5',         '3.2.0-beta.6',
  '3.2.0-beta.7',   '3.2.0-beta.8',         '3.2.0',
  '3.2.1',          '3.2.2',                '3.2.3',
  '3.2.4',          '3.2.5',                '3.2.6',
  '3.2.7',          '3.2.8',                '3.2.9',
  '3.2.10',         '3.2.11',               '3.2.12',
  '3.2.13',         '3.2.14',               '3.2.15',
  '3.2.16',         '3.2.17',               '3.2.18',
  '3.2.19',         '3.2.20',               '3.2.21',
  '3.2.22',         '3.2.23',               '3.2.24',
  '3.2.25',         '3.2.26'
]
```